# Ruby SSLserver closes on SSLERROR

Tags: ruby, ssl, error-handling, openssl

I have a simple SSL server in ruby:

```
require "socket"
require "openssl"
tcp_server = TCPServer.new("0.0.0.0", 8443)
ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ctx.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read params["ssl-key"]
ctx.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read params["ssl-cert"]
server = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLServer.new(tcp_server, ctx)

#client handling code
loop do
client = server.accept
client.puts("Hello!")
client.close
end
```

When I start the server, it works as expected and I can connect to it using a client that uses SSL properly, but when I connect to it with a client using a normal tcp socket, I get `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError` and the program quits. I can rescue the exception and the program does not exit, but I can not connect to the server from any type of client.

Comment: It is perfectly normal that you get an exception if the TLS handshake fails, you have to properly deal with this. *" I can rescue the exception and the program does not exit, but I can not connect to the server from any type of client."* - unfortunately you don't show how you deal with the exception, maybe its wrong. Please update your question to show how you are dealing with the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure, this is weird. Possibly, you could try to start a new server and kill the old one? I think the server is still running, but is inactive.

Comment: This seems to work, but is too slow for my usecase.